# Customize checkout scm

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Trying to setup a pipeline for .NET web application and the checkout scm creates a directory name (appname_string). this directory name is more than 248 characters and this is causing the Build step to fail (Directory name should be less than 248 characters). Is there anyway to just have the application name as folder name in checkout step instead of appending those unnecessary strings?

Answer (score 0):

you can try using the checkout parameters instead

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: 'subdirectory1']], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'repo1.git']]])
```